# Convert LPVOID bitmap pointer to QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-resource

I am trying to load in a BMP image from a resources folder into a QPixmap object. However, I can't read the bytes even though rewriting those bytes to a new file makes a correct copy of the original. Here is my loading method:

```cpp
QPixmap* GUIMain::loadImage(int name) {
    // Resource loading, works fine
    HRSRC rc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(name), RT_BITMAP);

    if (rc == NULL) {
        printf("INVALID RESOURCE ADDRESS (%i)\n", name);
        return new QPixmap();
    }

    HGLOBAL rcData = LoadResource(NULL, rc);
    LPVOID data = LockResource(rcData);
    DWORD data_size = SizeofResource(NULL, rc);

    // Rewrite file to new file, works fine
    ofstream output("E:\\" + to_string(name) + ".bmp", std::ios::binary);
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = { 'MB', 54 + data_size, 0, 0, 54 };
    output.write((char*)&bfh, sizeof(bfh));
    output.write((char*)data, data_size);
    output.close();

    // Need to return, can't get bytes working
    return new QPixmap(/*?*/);
}
```

This method is called with the definitions from the `resource.h` file.

I have tried to use a `stringstream` with the same calls as the `ofstream`, followed by using that stream as a source for the `QPixmap`, but the stream didn't produce the same output.

Here are the relevant parts of my `resource.h` file:

```cpp
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     101
#define IDB_BITMAP2                     102
```

Here is my `Resource.rc` file:

```cpp
IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "E:\\Downloads\\onIcon.bmp"

IDB_BITMAP2             BITMAP                  "E:\\Downloads\\offIcon.bmp"
```

I know I should be using the Qt tools for resource management, but I don't have the capabilities to do so.

Comment: Why can't you load the image directly into the `QPixmap`? There is a constructor which accepts a file path and image type: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-2. Also, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#load and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData.

Comment: While I would like to do that, the problem is that I do not want to be dependent on any filesystem structure. Those methods would link me to an absolute path (unless there is a way to load files from a VS solution that would work as an EXE).

Comment: I mentioned the `loadFromData` function above because it looks like it initializes the `QPixmap` from a `char` buffer which would decouple how the data is retrieved from how it is loaded into the `QPixmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QPixmap::loadFromData(...) to create a QPixmap from bytes in bmp format, but you also need to not declare the resource as "BITMAP" in the .rc file.

Bitmap resources are intended to be used with [LoadBitmap(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadbitmapa) or [LoadImage(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea) and are stored in the .exe with the bitmap header stripped off. ([Raymond Chen discusses this here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091211-00/?p=15693)) Since you are not using LoadBitmap  set the type of the resources to be arbitrary binary data, e.g.

```
IDB_BITMAP1 RCDATA "E:\\Downloads\\onIcon.bmp"
```

and then implement your image loading routine as below:

```
QPixmap* GUIMain::loadImage(int name) {

    // ...

    HGLOBAL rcData = LoadResource(NULL, rc);
    LPVOID data = LockResource(rcData);
    DWORD data_size = SizeofResource(NULL, rc);

    QPixmap* pm = new QPixmap();
    pm->loadFromData( static_cast<uchar*>(data), data_size, "bmp");

    return pm;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but sadly it didn't work. It might be because of missing header information, but I'm not sure. When I tried saving my images without adding the proper header information, I just got an empty file. The modified method just returns an empty pixmap.

Comment: oh actually rc.exe is stripping the header. See here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091211-00/?p=15693
so make the resource type RCDATA not bitmap and everythign should work